# Convert loop system to a single equation

Tags: c++, nested-loops

I've been attempting to convert a set of nested loops into a single equation and need some help.

The code to calculate my sequences is as follows:

`

```
int Astart = 1;
int Bstart = 1;
int Cstart = 1;
int Dstart = 1;

int Ai = 6;
int Bi = 2;
int Ci = 3;
int Di = 4;

int A,B,C,D = 0;

int i=0;
for(int a=Astart;a<Astart+Ai; a++)
{
    for(int b=Bstart;b<Bstart+Bi; b++)
    {
        for(int c=Cstart;c<Cstart+Ci;c++)
        {
            for(int d=DStart;d<Dstart+Di;d++)
            {
                std::cout << "[" << i << "]" << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << std::endl;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

All I need to do is have a single for loop running the number of permutations to replicate the behavior of the nested loop. i.e.

```
for(int i=0; i<(Ai*Bi*Ci*Di); i++)
{

<Insert equations here!>

}
```

What I'm really after is a function that takes an integer in the sequence and calculates the values of A,B,C and D based on the variables Ai,Bi,Ci,Di and Astart,Bstart,Cstart,Dstart.

Also, this system relies on the order of the nested loops, is there a method of not relying on the order to get the values A,B,C,D?

Any help would be great,

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: yourcodewouldbeeasiertoreadwithspacesbutIknowthisdoesntreallyhelpanswerthequestion

Comment: why would you do that?  this here is MORE readable and more maintainable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the divide (`/`) and remainder (`%`) operators.

```
93 / 10 = 9
93 % 10 = 3
```

...

Comment: +1 More explicitly, inside the loop you can have statements like `int c = CStart + i / Di % Ci;`, extracting each of the `a`-`d` values from `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The variables `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are always zero, since you initialize them and never use them again.

Comment: Yes, this is a section of code, not the full code. This didn't really need explaining and isn't in any way part of the question but thanks ever so much for pointing it out. Thanks also for pointing  out that there are no spaces it was after all this that was causing me my biggest problem

Comment: @Chris: What I was referring to is that the variable `a`, which you increment in the loop, is not the same as the variable `A`.